# TFSReg in 2010 Beta 2?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

does anybody know what is the equivalent of the TFSReg.exe command-line tool in 2010 Beta 2? I cannot find it anywhere, I searched the entire Program Files tree.  Was it renamed? Moved? Replaced by something else? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It's actually been removed from TFS 2010 (since you'll be able to set a lot of those details using the TFS Administration Console UI.)  If you're needed to configure a custom service, then you can use the details that Jim Lamb provides in this MSDN Forum Post:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/tfsprerelease/thread/fcec76a1-a772-4ecf-84f3-ad48d67762dc

Comment: Great question - it was a pre-release MSDN forum post so not sure where the new location will be.  I'll take a look for it.